# How to draw custom pie ring chart like this image in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas, flutter-layout

I have to custom like this image. Can anyone help me with example ?

I tried some lib in pub dev but not success.[image: 1]

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This result you can achieve with [mrx_charts](https://pub.dev/packages/mrx_charts) library

[image]